# jquery drag and rotate to angle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am using jQuery UI to drag and drop an image. I also want to rotate the image 360 degrees so I can move and rotate it like in Photoshop. I am using the [jQuery rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) to rotate the image on click, but I want to select a corner and drag to rotate the image to any angle.

Live JS: http://jsfiddle.net/87jaR/

JavaScript code:

```
var test = 5;
$(function() 
{
    $('#rotate').draggable({ containment: 'frame' });
    $('#frame img').live('mousedown', function(event) 
    {
        test = test + 15;
        $(this).rotate({ angle: test });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pls check with this one, Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthkc/frz8J/

```
var dragging = false

$(function() {
var target = $('#target')
target.mousedown(function() {
    dragging = true
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    dragging = false
})
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (dragging) {

        var mouse_x = e.pageX;
        var mouse_y = e.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - 10, mouse_y - 10);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        target.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        target.css('-moz-transform-origin', '0% 40%');
        target.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        target.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0% 40%');
        target.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        target.css('-o-transform-origin', '0% 40%');
        target.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        target.css('-ms-transform-origin', '0% 40%');
    }
})
```

})

1) **Here** `deg` **means** `degree`, **Either you can use** `rad` **for** `radians`

2) **You can change the rotating point by changing** `transform-origin`

**For Eg**: `transform-origin: 50% 50%` will move the rotating point to center.

Comment: Thanks for this code! do you know how to set rotate center of the circle? not atan2()

Comment: @user1775888: 'deg' stands for 'degrees', you can also use values in 'radians using 'rad'.

Comment: @user1775888: are you looking to rotate a circle from its center? if so, setting the value of transform-origin to 50% 50% will do the job

Comment: @PrasanthKC is their way we can implement same functionality for mobile deivces??.. 
Thanks:)..

Comment: @Beginer i think you should have a mouse to touch event converter, there exist some cross platform js libraries that can convert mouse events to touch.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the first argument to `Math.atan2` should actually be the y-coord and the second the x-coord ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)). Also, the -10 represents the body margin.

Answer (score 5):

this works for me. http://plnkr.co/edit/xaCWl9Havv1ow7bhMTf2?p=preview

```
(function() {

    var RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI;            
    var dial = $("#box");
    dial.centerX = dial.offset().left + dial.width()/2;
    dial.centerY =  dial.offset().top + dial.height()/2;


    var offset, dragging=false;
    dial.mousedown(function(e) {
      dragging = true;
      offset = Math.atan2(dial.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - dial.centerX);
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
      dragging = false
    })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      if (dragging) { 

        var newOffset = Math.atan2(dial.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - dial.centerX);
        var r = (offset - newOffset) * RAD2DEG;

        dial.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
      }
    })
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

I will leave this here in case someone else had the same issues I did:

The answers here are good but if you want it to work on mobile devices and IE <10, you need a library. It took me about 1 week to find it and it gets the job done.

[library link](http://greensock.com/draggable)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is this software free?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar function for a project, but mine also works on touch devices like the iPad or Android Tablets:

http://jsfiddle.net/C3tuD/46/

You need jQuery and a library for rotation which you can find [here](http://jqueryrotate.com), then activate it via `$("#ObjectToBeRotated").rotateAble();`

Source Code:

```
$.fn.rotateAble = function() {
var offset = null;
var dragging = false;

var RotationTarget = $(this); // Save target, cause $(this) doesn't work from MouseUp and MouseMove

// Mouse
var MouseDown = function(e) {
    dragging = true;

    offset = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
    };
    $("div#rotation").text("MouseDown");
};
var MouseUp = function() {
    dragging = false;
    $("div#rotation").text("MouseUp");
};
var MouseMove = function(e) {
    var mouse_x = e.pageX - offset.x;
    var mouse_y = e.pageY - offset.y;
    //$("div#rotation").text("Move: " + mouse_x + " " + mouse_y);
    if (dragging) {

        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x, mouse_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        RotationTarget.rotate(degree);

        //$("div#rotation").text(degree);
    }
};

// Touch
var TouchStart = function(e) {
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    var pos = $(this).position();

    offset = {
        x: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX,
        y: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY
    };
};
var TouchMove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var orig = e.originalEvent;

    var mouse_x = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - offset.x;
    var mouse_y = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - offset.y;

    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x, mouse_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
    $(this).rotate(degree);
    //$("div#rotation").text(degree);
};

this.bind("touchstart", TouchStart);
this.bind("touchmove", TouchMove);
$(this).bind("mousedown", MouseDown);
$(document).bind("mouseup", MouseUp);
$(document).bind("mousemove", MouseMove);
};
```

Comment: `JqueryRotate.js` results in `404`

Answer (score -13):

This is not possible in JavaScript to rotate at any angle. This is possible in IE as MS has implemented activeX control in IE for that purpose but not a cross browser solution.

Anyway If you still interested to invest your time, you can use SVG which is capable of any any sort of such task but still it has cross browser problems. IE6/7/8 does not have any SVG implemented even though u can use ChromeFrame google project to solve that problem or if you can find any SVG plugin for IE.