# How to rotate an element on drag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I'm creating a website with a rotating wheel. The user should be able to rotate this wheel with dragging it with mouse. I implemented this in jQuery and it works(rotates). But it behaves as expected just between 90 degrees and 180 degrees. When it rotates more or less than this range, I see some unexpected bounces.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isDragging = false;

    $("#box").mousemove(function(e){
        if(isDragging){
            e.preventDefault();

            var rx = $(this).width() / 2;
            var ry = $(this).height() / 2;

            var px = e.clientX - $(this).offset().left - rx;
            var py = e.clientY - $(this).offset().top - ry;

            var a = Math.atan2(py,px) * 180 / Math.PI + 90;

            if(py <= 0 && px < 0){a = 360 + a;}

            $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate(" + a + "deg)");
        }
    });

    $("#box").mousedown(function(){
        isDragging = true;
    });

    $("*").mouseup(function(){
        isDragging = false;
    });
});
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: It seems you like the capital letters too much.

Comment: I Love Camel Case Typing. lol

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the answer posted here.

[How to make object rotate with drag, how to get a rotate point around the origin use sin or cos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599738/how-to-make-object-rotate-with-drag-how-to-get-a-rotate-point-around-the-origin)

Here is the working fiddle from their answer

http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/tBgLh/11/

it involves making your html look similar to this.

```
<div class="draggable_wp">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your if(isDragging) clause:

```
var element = document.getElementById("rotatable");
var mouseX = e.pageX || e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
var mouseY = e.pageY || e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var s_rad = Math.atan2(
        mouseY - rect.top - rect.height / 2, 
        mouseX - rect.left - rect.width / 2
    );
var degree = Math.round(90 + (s_rad * (180 / (Math.PI))) / 15) * 15;
element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
```